# ElasticSearch : how to use minimum_should_match in this query?

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I have this query in my rails app:

```
query = { query: { bool: { must: [], minimum_should_match:"75%" }}, sort: { _score: { order: :desc }, year: { order: :desc, ignore_unmapped: true }} }
    query[:query][:bool][:must] << { match: { winery: @winery.name }} # use winery field, not searchable
    query[:query][:bool][:must] << { term: { country_id: @winery.country_id }} if !@winery.country_id.nil?
    query[:query][:bool][:must] << { term: { region_id: @winery.region_id }} if !@winery.region_id.nil?          
    @results = Wine.search(query)
```

The fact is don't know where to put the *minimum_should_match* option. It is allowed only after the *must*. The problem is I can change the value of 75%, nothing changes in my results.

My goal is to use it only with *match: { winery: @winery.name }* field.

--

For example, I'm currently searching for *Quinta da Romaneira* as @winery.name.

And I got:

- Quinta da Romaneira
- Pinteveira

as results.

So I want the query to only return the first, the second ngrams distance is too long.

With a more classical query like this one:

```
self.search(query: {match: {winery: {query:search, minimum_should_match:"75%"}}})
```

the *minimum_should_match* is working fine.

So how to change my first query so that the minimum_should_match can have an impact on results ?

My mapping is using ngrams on the @winery.name field:

```
settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 1 }, analysis: {
      analyzer: {
        custom_index_analyzer: {
          type: "custom",
          tokenizer: "standard",
          filter: ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "custom_word_delimiter", "custom_fr_stopwords", "custom_en_stopwords", "custom_de_stopwords", "custom_es_stopwords", "custom_it_stopwords", "custom_pt_stopwords", "custom_unique_token", "custom_tokenizer"]
        },
        custom_search_analyzer: {
          type: "custom",
          tokenizer: "standard",
          filter: ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "custom_word_delimiter", "custom_fr_stopwords", "custom_en_stopwords", "custom_de_stopwords", "custom_es_stopwords", "custom_it_stopwords", "custom_pt_stopwords", "custom_unique_token", "custom_tokenizer"]
        }
      },
      filter: {
        custom_word_delimiter: {
          type: "word_delimiter"
        },
        custom_unique_token: {
          type: "unique",
          only_on_same_position: "false"
        },      
        custom_tokenizer: {
          type: "nGram",
          min_gram: "3",
          max_gram: "8",
          token_chars: [ "letter", "digit" ]
        }
      }
    } do
      mappings dynamic: 'false' do
        indexes :winery, analyzer: "custom_index_analyzer", search_analyzer: "custom_search_analyzer"
        indexes :name, analyzer: "custom_index_analyzer", search_analyzer: "custom_search_analyzer"
        indexes :country_id, type: "integer"
        indexes :region_id, type: "integer"
      end
    end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is analyzer for `searchable` field? And are you looking for fuzzy search of full-text search - I mean it looks like there is a little mess around `Levenstein Dist` vs. `Min Shoul Match in DisMax`.

Comment: "searchable" field and/or "winery" field have the same analyzer with ngrams. I edited my message to add the full mapping. Forget "searchable" field (it was my example). The problem is only with winery field.